# How to apply identified signature to a Mac bundle?

Tags: macos, bundle, digital-signature, codesign

I'm having a problem signing the mac bundle of my application.

When I codesign --verify --verbose my bundle it says:

> valid on disk satisfies its Designated Requirement

And codesign -dv --verbose=4 on my bundle says:

> Executable=/Volumes/MYBUNDLE/MYAPP.app/Contents/MacOS/MYEXECUTABLE Identifier=com.MYCOMPANY.MYSOFTWARE Format=bundle with Mach-O thin
>   (x86_64) CodeDirectory v=20100 size=29841 flags=0x0(none)
>   hashes=1485+3 location=embedded Hash type=sha1 size=20
>   CDHash=607c7d2c518d03e1c8c06f49d9a8c413fde81484 Signature size=4872
>   Authority=MYSIGNATURENAME Authority=Symantec Class 3 SHA256 Code
>   Signing CA Authority=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification
>   Authority - G5 Signed Time=Oct 27, 2016, 4:27:47 PM Info.plist
>   entries=9 TeamIdentifier=not set Sealed Resources version=2 rules=12
>   files=340 Internal requirements count=1 size=108

And it runs fine on my computer.
Still, when it is downloaded from the Internet (embedded into a DMG file and then copied into Applications) I have the following error message:
"YOURAPP can't be opened because it is from an unidentified developer"

What did I did wrong ?

Thanks !

Comment: Signature must come from Apple, you buy it from them by registering to their developer program for 99 dollars per year. It starts with "Developer ID : yourappleid"